# Alternatives to "The following (standards) shall be followed:"

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

Can anyone suggest a good alternative to "The following (standards) shall be followed:"? I'm trying to avoid using "following" twice in a sentence.

Comment: 'followed' has a bazillian synonyms. Pick one.

Comment: @TusharRaj - The only alternative I can think of is "adhered to", but that carries more rigor than "followed". If you can think of some more, I would be grateful.

Comment: act in accordance with, abide by, adhere to, stick to, keep to, comply with, conform to, obey, observe, heed, pay attention to, note, have regard to, mind, bear in mind, take to heart, be guided by, accept, yield to, defer to, respect

Comment: How about "These standards shall be followed."  Or, "You must follow the standards listed here."  Or, "The listed standards shall be followed:...<list>"

Comment: @A.Ellett - Not all are Standards. Some are Codes, Rules, Guidelines...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The following standards must be [met](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/meet)*.

> 3 Fulfil or satisfy (a need, requirement, or condition):

*The following procedures must be [used](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/use).*

> 1 Take, hold, or deploy (something) as a means of accomplishing or
>   achieving something; employ:

*The following [codes, rules, guidelines] must be [applied](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/apply).*

> 2.1 [WITH OBJECT] Bring or put into operation or use:

*Oxford English Dictionary Online*

Answer (score 0):

**Implemented**: put (a decision, plan, agreement etc) into effect.

This term is widely used in the workplace and would be appropriate to include in instruction manuals and related documents.

*Source*:    [Oxford Dict.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/implement)